# Test a variable in Makefile target

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I am trying to get it to work, but it seems that the variable is not passed correctly to the if statement as it does not "enter" the if loop

```
apply_test:
                $(eval var=$(shell bash -c "echo 1"))        
                echo $(var)
ifeq ($(var),1)
        echo "inside the stmt"
        $(eval var=$(shell bash -c "echo 2")) 
endif
                echo $(var)
```

Generally, I try to evaluate the return value of a function, to perform subsequent conditional settings, e.g. set a new variable inside the if-stmt.

What´s wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, pretty much everything here is problematic :).  You haven't given any explanation of *why* you're trying to do something so convoluted, but pro tips:

- Any time you're using make conditionals like `ifeq` etc. inside a recipe it's likely that it won't do what you want, unless you're very sure you completely understand the expansion rules of makefiles.
- Any time you're using `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe, it's almost always a bad idea.
- Any time you're using `$(eval ...)` inside a recipe, it's almost 100% definitely a bad idea.

However to deal with only your immediate problem: `ifeq` is processed while the makefile is being *parsed*.  Recipes are not run until after the entire makefile is parsed and make decides which targets to run.  So when make is parsing the makefile and looking at `ifeq`, the variable `var` has not been set yet and so it evaluates to the empty string and is never equal to `1`.

**ETA**

Without knowing anything else about your requirements I'll say that the "right" way to implement this is using shell operations inside the recipe.  That would look like this:

```
apply_test:
        var=$$(echo 1) ; \       
        echo $$var; \
        if [ $$var = 1 ]; then \
            echo "inside the stmt"; \
            var=$$(echo 2); \
        fi; \
        echo $$var
```

Comment: ok makes sense. But how can I implement something like this. Say, I need to check the return value of a variable in an if-stmt and then alter that variable to us it later on.

Comment: This is why I said that without knowing what you're actually trying to do it's hard to answer.  There are a lot of ways to do it and the best way depends on what you want to do.  For example, why are you trying to set _make_ variables using `eval`?  That's just a bad idea.  Is it really needed?  Are you trying to use this value of the `var` variable anywhere _outside_ of this recipe?

Comment: No, I´m not using it outside. It is just necessary to perform a check to perform subsequent steps. So all I really need is to being able to store variables and "use" them later on :)